# react bootstrap table2 pagination warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I want to resolve this warning. Because every time I click a button. The error count increases.

I tried to remove "`<PaginationListStandalone {...paginationProps} />`" this line and the error is gone but I need that pagination

```
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit';
import paginationFactory, { PaginationProvider, PaginationListStandalone, SizePerPageDropdownStandalone } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
```

```
const options = {
  custom: true,
  paginationSize: 1,
  pageStartIndex: 1,
  alwaysShowAllBtns: true,
  withFirstAndLast: false,
  firstPageText: 'First',
  prePageText: <i className="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-left"></i>,
  nextPageText: <i className="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-right"></i>,
  lastPageText: 'Last',
  nextPageTitle: 'Next page',
  prePageTitle: 'Previous page',
  firstPageTitle: 'First page',
  lastPageTitle: 'Last page',
  showTotal: false,
  sizePerPageList: [{
    text: '5', value: 5
  }, {
    text: '10', value: 10
  }, {
    text: '15', value: 15
  }, {
    text: '20', value: 20
  }]
};
```

```
const contentTable = ({ paginationProps, paginationTableProps }) => (
  <SC.Table_Area className="table-area extractor-table">
    <ToolkitProvider
      keyField="id"
      columns={columns}
      data={products}
      search
    >
      {
        toolkitprops => (
          <>
            <div className="header-filter">
              <SizePerPageDropdownStandalone {...paginationProps} />
              <SearchBar {...toolkitprops.searchProps} />
            </div>
            <BootstrapTable
              striped
              expandRow={expandRow}
              cellEdit={cellEditFactory({ mode: 'click' })}
              noDataIndication="Table is Empty"
              {...toolkitprops.baseProps}
              {...paginationTableProps}
            />
            <div className="footer-filter">
              <PaginationListStandalone {...paginationProps} />
            </div>
          </>
        )
      }
    </ToolkitProvider>
  </SC.Table_Area>
);
```

```
<PaginationProvider pagination={paginationFactory(options)}>
   {contentTable}
</PaginationProvider>
```

I get the result I needed but I just want to remove the warning error on console.

Comment: I have used this thing, this table is a crap.  i changed to `react-table` which solves such issues. use your own logic for pagination change. with this server side pagination is also possible. the table one you used does not support serverside pagination

Comment: Noted Akhil Aravind. Thank you for that Information